# asp-route in table row not passing id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor

asp-route does not seem to be sending an Id over to my View Method correctly, when using it within a  tag. The id gets passed in as "null". 
When I use it with an a tag it works fine(except it doesn't open a modal); however, I want to make the whole row clickable to edit.

I tried to check casing to make sure it wasn't something silly; however, when paste the same code into an  tag it has 0 issues. When I look in the console, I can see that asp-route-id is pulling the correct id. It hits the controller, and goes through the if(user == null) because it comes in as null.

HTML:

```html
    @model PortalDev.Models.ApplicationUser

    <tr data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-target="#editUser" data-url="@Url.Action("EditUser")" asp-action="EditUser" asp-controller="Administration" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">
        <td class="text-left">@Model.Id</td>
        <td class="text-left">@Model.UserName</td>
        <td class="text-left">@Model.Email>
        <td class="text-left">@Model.PhoneNumber</td>
        <td class="text-left">@Model.City</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" id="btnOpen" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SendEmail">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
            </button>
            <a asp-action="EditUser" asp-controller="Administration" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Controller:

```c#
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(string id)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"User with Id = {id} cannot be found";
                return View("NotFound");
            }

            var userClaims = await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
            var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            var model = new EditUserViewModel
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                Email = user.Email,
                UserName = user.UserName,
                City = user.City,
                Claims = userClaims.Select(c => c.Value).ToList(),
                Roles = userRoles
            };
            return PartialView("~/Views/Modals/_EditUserModalPartial.cshtml", model);
        }
```

Expected behavior is to click on the table row and it brings up a modal with the EditUserViewModel

Comment: Is the `Id` actually a `string` (and not an `int`)? Does it work it you change your method to `EditUser([FromRoute] string id)`?

Comment: @crgolden yeah, it's actually a string, it resembles a GUID but has a type of string. The only time it works is if I do an a tag on the front end. Everything else I have tried doesn't work (including [FromRoute]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `data-url="@Url.Action("EditUser")"` with `data-url="@Url.Action("EditUser", new {Id = Model.Id})"`. This will generate correct Url.